# Repeatedly apply a function to a list and accumulate the output in a string

Tags: bash

I have a function which takes 1 integer argument either `X` or `O` based on some test of that, like this simple `is_even` function:

```
function is_even {
  if [ $(( $1 % 2)) -eq 0 ]; then echo "O";
  else echo "X";
  fi 
}
```

Now I want to call this for every item in some list, and generate a string with all the answers. So if I call it for the list 1, 5, 2, 8, 7, I want the string `X X O O X`.

Basically this is the map function x -> is_even(x) applied to the list.

What I'm using now is

```
result=""
for i in {1..10}; do
 result+="$(is_even $i) " 
done
```

Which seems to give the right output, but wondering if there is a more canonical or succinct way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's "canonical" or "succinct" here is partly in the eye of the beholder.

As an alternative to the explicit `for` loop, we can use `xargs`.  The first step is to make sure the `is_even` shell function has been exported:

```
$ export -f is_even
```

Now, we can create an array of the results:

```
$ arr=($(echo {1..10} | xargs -n1 bash -c 'is_even $1' Even))
```

We can verify that `arr` has the right values:

```
$ echo "${arr[@]}"
X O X O X O X O X O
```

#### The Function

The test `[ $(( $1 % 2)) -eq 0 ]` is unnecessarily complicated.  An alternative form for the function is:

```
even() { if (( $1 % 2)); then echo X; else echo 0; fi; }
```

This works because arithmetic evaluation, `((...))`, returns true if the result is nonzero and false otherwise.

Also, because it is good practice, we have used here the POSIX form of function definition. The `function` keyword is non-portable.

Comment: Clever, thanks! You are right about "eye of the beholder" - I was mostly wondering if there was some kind of "functional" mapping type stuff available, and I guess `xargs` kind of bits the bill :)